# Batch converter for lightwave models

Tags: python, scripting, import, file-format

Is there some way to batch-convert [LWO](https://fileinfo.com/extension/lwo) models to Blender?
I have thousands of interior models that I have to convert to Blender format.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you already tried converting one lwo model into another format or have you tried importing a lwo model into blender? There is an addon you can use to import LWO into Blender https://github.com/nangtani/blender-import-lwo. Once you figure out how to use the addon, you should be able to write a python script that loops through each lwo and import them.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been thinkin on a solution like that. But searching for a solution like 3DBrowser or something similiar.